# Liquibase: Error Reading Changelog File: Found 2 files that match /liquibase/main-changelog.xml

Tags: kubernetes, liquibase, configmap

In kubernetes environment I placed all liquibase changelog files in ConfigMap which than referenced to volumeMount as follows:

```yaml
...
          volumeMounts:
            - name: my-vol
              mountPath: /liquibase
...
      volumes:
        - name: my-vol
          configMap:
            name: my-cm
```

I defined main-changelog.xml with liquibase variable on start and get following error:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Error Reading Changelog File: Found 2 files that match /liquibase/main-changelog.xml: file:/liquibase/..2023_06_19_03_58_35.3720542680/main-changelog.xml, file:/liquibase/main-changelog.xml
```

In filesystem of kubernetes pods it looks as follows:

```bash
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jun 19 08:16 ..
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Jun 19 08:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 19 08:16 ..2023_06_19_08_16_53.3878877458
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   32 Jun 19 08:16 ..data -> ..2023_06_19_08_16_53.3878877458
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   32 Jun 19 08:16 main-changelog.xml -> ..data/main-changelog.xml
```

As it can be seen kubernetes creates internally a symlink of files and references with ConfigMap, which I assume liquibase has the problem with. Is there any suggestions to fix this problem?

Comment: I can not use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50687707/12501050 workaround in kubernetes context as i have many liquibase changelogs and defining all files is very bad option.

Comment: Can you check the below github information that can be useful to you.
https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/2818#issuecomment-1167873963

Comment: As per the mentioned link https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/2104
"if a path matches multiple files in the search-path, we fail with an error". The fix for that is to update your searchpath to not include duplicate files, or to use the liquibase.duplicateFileMode setting.

Comment: Let me know if the provided information was helpful. I am happy to assist you in case of any queries.

Comment: I used e.g. ```--duplicate-file-mode=WARN``` and getting the following error ```Unexpected argument(s): "--duplicate-file-mode=WARN". For detailed help, try 'liquibase --help' or 'liquibase <command-name> --help'```

Comment: P.S. I use the ```Liquibase Version: 4.9.1```